# Handling Objects coming from RMI server and delegating to objects in the client

Tags: java, rmi

I am creating a instant chat application using RMI. The server sends through certain objects which I need the client to handle. 
For example the server will send a `JoinedGroupOperation` class. In my client application I need to recognise the class and let my handler take over (`HandleJoinedGroupOperation`). This class will do a bunch of stuff on the client side.

My question is how can I handle classes that come from the server so I don't need to do any if statements? ie

```
if(server.getResponse() instanceof JoinedGroupOperation){
    HandleJoinedGroupOperation handle = new HandleJoinedGroupOperation();
    handle.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible option in your case is to use [chain of responsibility](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41786/Chain-of-Responsibility-Design-Pattern)  design patern.
You should create some abstraction of your possible handlers(like `HandleJoinedGroupOperation`), then link those handlers(preferebly at start time). As a example, create an interface

```
 interface OperationHandler {
     void handle(Operation op);
}
```

where `Operation` is also a basic type for all possible operations. This type(`Operation`) can contain a field of enum type OperationType:

```
enum OperationType {
...
}
```

Then in the concrete handlers you can simply check this field(although it will contain `if` statement, but those statements will be encapsulated in each specific handler)

As a simple example, here is a default implementation of a handler

```
class SimpleHandler implements OperationHandler {
 private OperationHandler next;

 public void handle(Operation op) {
     if (op.getType() == OperationType.SOMEYOURTYPE) {
        //do some stuff
     } else {
        next.handle(op);
     }
 }
}
```

In this case your `server.getResponse()` method simply will return basic type of `Operation` hierarchy

Also read the article to get more information